# Calling a function with arguments

Tags: java, function, arguments

I code in Python usually and I've started learning Java, but I'm confused in calling a method with arguments. Indeed in Python you can call a function with an argument like this:

```
my_function(argument)
```

after having created it like this :

```
def my_function(argument):
    #Here I can use my argument like this
    print(argument) #if argument is a string
```

But I haven't found how to do the same thing in Java. In fact I would especially like do this :

```
return new webPage() //this call my file named "webPage"
//But when I'm calling, I want to send the url of the
//web page and recover it in the other file
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: What do you want to achieve by placing `new` in `return new webPage()`?

Comment: When you create a new object you are calling that class' constructor, so you need to create a constructor that takes an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it but with little difference
Like:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double a= scan.nextInt();
    double b= scan.nextInt();
    sum(a,b);
    sub(a,b)
    mul(a,b);
    div(a,b);
}
void sum(double a,double b){
    System.out.println("Sum :"+(a+b));
}
void sub(double a,double b){
    System.out.println("Sub :"+(a-b));
}void mul(double a,double b){
    System.out.println("Mul :"+(a*b));
}void div(double a,double b){
    System.out.println("Div :"+(a/b));
}
```

console calculator;
In this:

method is called like `sum(a,b)` you should know about signature of method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) now its method which is called look like `void sum(double a,double b)`.

**NOTE:** in method `void sum(double a,double b)` a and b is its local variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
But how I must to do to call a function which is in an other Java file ?